# How to access another jar within jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I have a Java project say "JarProject".

Let's describe the project strucutre:

```
JarProject
   -src          // first folder within "JarProject"
     -package1
      -mainProgram.java         // which has to execute myLocalJar.jar

   -Jar      // another folder within "JarProject"
     -myLocalJar.jar
```

From the above structure , "mainProgram.java" has to execute myLocalJar.jar file which is available in the "Jar" folder.

How to access the "Jar" folder within the project?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: sorry, i can't get your reply.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Yes. i am using eclipse.

Comment: Do you mean that myLocalJar.jar is an executable jar and you want mainProgram to issue an operating system command that will execute it?

Comment: What @yiannis asked, or do you want to include classes from the jar?

Comment: mainProgram have a menu. while clicking on menu, myLocalJar.jar has to execute.

Comment: No. i wont include classes from the jar. i want to only run that jar.

Comment: show this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599290/executing-a-different-jar-file-from-another-java-program

Comment: could you explain this structure "/temp/jss.jar" (i am asking about the location of "/temp" folder) from the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599290/executing-a-different-jar-file-from-another-java-program

Answer (score 0):

If it's an executable `.jar`, then I suggest you use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).