# Run a jar from a jar

Tags: java, jar, process, executable-jar, processbuilder

I have a java program in which i have this code,

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "TEST");
String pathToJar = ClassRewriter.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()+"ClassRewriter.class";
System.out.println(pathToJar);
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("javaw "+pathToJar);
Process process = pb.start();
```

I have a java program in a class called `classrewriter`, and i am trying to start that program from within its main method but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: This question might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program

Comment: Possible duplicate [Executing a different Jar file from another java program](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6599961/1563878)

Comment: The command line should be more like "javax -jar pathToJar"

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int runCommand(String command) throws Exception 
    {
    Process s= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    return s.exitValue();
}
```

So you write:

```
 runCommand("java -jar "+pathToJar);
```

But it isn't recommend, because it isn't supported on all OSes (for example linux or mac).