# execute jar file in java program

Tags: java

I want to create an java program to compress an css file using YUI
I am new learner in java.

My Code is:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Run extends Object
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Calling jar");

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -Xmx32m -jar yui.jar in.css");    
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(p.getInputStream());
        synchronized(p) 
        {
            p.waitFor();
        }

        System.out.println(p.exitValue());

        int b = 0;
        while((b = bis.read()) > 0)
        {
            System.out.print((char)b);    
        }

        System.out.println("Called jar");
    }
}
```

I took reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599290/executing-a-different-jar-file-from-another-java-program).

the command:

```
java -Xmx32m -jar yui.jar in.css
```

works fine in cmd but I get no output when I run above program
the output I get for above is:

```
Calling jar
1
Called jar
```

Please tell Me what I am doing wrong or what is the right way of doing this.

Comment: Why don't integrate yui in your code as showed in http://blog.teamextension.com/yui-compressor-in-java-246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the "1" because there is nothing to read in the stream.

I'm guessing that you're trying to run the file from Eclipse or some other IDE. If so, you need to place your `yui.jar` and `in.css` files to same directory relative to where your `Run` class is.

If you're using default run configurations, you'll just want to put the files into the root directory of your eclipse project. For example, this works for me:

```
Test
  src
    com
      test
        Run.java
  yui.jar
  in.css
```

A better way to handle your situation is to use absolute or relative paths instead of just specifiying `yui.jar` or `in.css`. Create two variables for the two relative paths and then create the command string.

Comment: do you mean in src directory?

Comment: Yes, the example package I gave was com.test, but anywhere within the src.